# JQuery popup on textbox click in asp.net is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have functionality in which I have to select Customer from dropdownlist then it will fetch that customer's addresses. 
If I click on Address TextBox, a JQuery popup will open up & show all the addresses.
I'm trying to open JQuery popup but it is showing this error in console whenever I click on textbox txtFromAddress.
[image: Error]

**.aspx page code**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFromCustomer" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlFromCustomer_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFromAddress" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        PopupForPanel();
    });

    function PopupForPanel() {
        $("[id*=txtFromAddress]").click(function () {
            ShowFromAddress();
            return false;
        });
    }

    function ShowFromAddress() {
        $("#dialog1").dialog({
            title: "Select Address",
            width: 900,
            height: 300
        });
    }
</script>

<div id="dialog1" style="display: none">
    JQuery popup
    //display all address records based on selected customer
</div>
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the jquery.js and add the jquery-ui.min.js.

Comment: `<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>` => this attempts to load jQuery twice, because the first one added from CDN. Try remove this line.

Comment: Thanks. It worked.